# Manually rotate screen

Tags: android, rotation, screen, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Hs there any chance to rotate the screen on Android programmatically for the whole system?
Background is that I'm using a CMPC-device which features a non-Android-supported rotation sensor, and as a quick fix, I'm planning to write a small app that changes orientation for the entire system.
Is there any function available for this purpose?
I couldn't find anything on the documentation :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find what you want here :

http://www.anddev.org/rotate_screen_from_code_change_screen_orientation-t2687.html

Comment: Thanks - for me, this article looks like it would only work for the current application - not for the whole system - or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

App can't change orientation for entire system. I guess, you need to make custom build of Android for this purpose.

Comment: Is there any chance to change it during runtime in a custom build? Is it stored somewhere in a file?

Comment: Obviously many apps allow to change orientation for specific apps or the whole system on Play Store. It probably requires root only.